# Java: unite arrays

Tags: java

I want to unite two int arrays in Java. How can I improve the code? Maybe there is a function that already does that?

```
public class Unify{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] b = {4, 5, 6};
        int[] c = mylist(a, b);
        for (int x:c)
            System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static int[] mylist(int[] a, int[] b){
        int len = a.length + b.length;
        int[] c = new int[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            c[i] = a[i];
        for(int i = a.length, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++)
            c[i] = b[j];
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `concat()`? Why not use lists?

Answer (score 1):

In no particular order, you might use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to print the result. And, [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-)<sup>1</sup> to create your new array and copy `a`. Finally, [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPost, int length`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to copy `b` into `c`. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] b = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int[] c = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

Output is (successfully indicating the copied array `c`)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

<sup>1<sub>The Javadoc says (in part) that `copyOf` **returns** a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with zeros to obtain the specified length</sub></sup>